# Wrong result after for each loop. JSON

Tags: php, json, pdf

I have a JSON result file, what contains all links, but after a foreach loop, I miss almost every data.

I've debugged the code and change the explode from - to _ , but it didn't help.

```
$pdfs = preg_grep('~\.(pdf)$~', getDirContents($config['directory']));

$result = [];
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($pdfs);

foreach ($pdfs as $doc) {

    var_dump($doc);
    $url = explode("/", $doc);
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($doc);

    $text = $pdf->getText();
    $result[] = [
        'file' => $url[9],
        'text' => $text, 
    ];
}
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
fclose($fp);
```

What I except is that I can have everything that is included in the JSON file.

```
array(27) {
  [0]=>
  string(111) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/247Rostar-QRC-TR-A4-android-DEF.pdf"
  [1]=>
  string(107) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/247Rostar-QRC-TR-A4-iOs-DEF.pdf"
  [2]=>
  string(102) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/Anonimiseren Databases.pdf"
  [3]=>
  string(110) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/Arbeidstijdenwet in CAS.pdf"
  [4]=>
  string(128) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/Configuration Reference Manual - CAS 5,18.pdf"
  [5]=>
  string(128) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/Configuration Reference Manual - CAS 5,19.pdf"
}
string(111) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/247Rostar-QRC-TR-A4-android-DEF.pdf"
string(107) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/247Rostar-QRC-TR-A4-iOs-DEF.pdf"
string(102) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/Anonimiseren Databases.pdf"
string(110) "/home/***/domains/***.com/public_html/doc/documenten/something/Arbeidstijdenwet in CAS.pdf"
```

**Read this before you give a answer!**
The first array shows everything within the JSON file, and the array on the bottom shows the result after the for each loop.

After the method call on:

```
$pdf = $parser->parseFile($doc);
```

After this method call it failed.

Comment: Should `$url[9]` not be `$url[10]`?  You don't actually explain what is wrong, nor give us the actual result with what you were hoping for.

Comment: Is anything written to result.json? Otherwise, the script is hitting a fatal error somewhere. Check the error logs or set `display_errors=on` in php.ini.

Comment: Looking at your script, you're using explode to get the filename, relying on a specific number of (sub)directories. It would be better to use [`basename`](https://php.net/basename), so the script doesn't break when the path changes.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels everything will be written successful, but it in the foreach it failed to read all 5 rows, it only returns 4 after the method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$config["directory"] = "/my/path/to/pdfs/";    
$pdfs = glob("{$config["directory"]}*.pdf");
$result = [];

foreach($pdfs as $pdf) {

    $filename = pathinfo($doc, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($pdf);
    $text = $pdf->getText();
    $result[] = [
        "file" => $filename,
        "text" => $text
    ];

}

file_put_contents("results.json", json_encode($result));
```

It basically does the same thing, but with less fuzz.
You may need to tweak $config["directory"] to match the path where your PDF's are stored.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt fix the problem. I still get 4 pdf files from $pdf, but $pdfs contains 25 pdf files.

Comment: Any answer? @Anuga

Comment: what do you get if you do a `echo count($pdfs);` after `$result = [];`

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of `Smalot\PdfParser`, up to v0.12.0, the `parseFile()` method silences errors that occur while parsing the content of the PDF. See [Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php line 74](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/v0.12.0/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php#L74).

This issue was [fixed in v0.13.0](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/v0.13.0/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php#L71). Make sure you're running at least v0.13.

---

Even in the latest version, the `@` operator is still used to silence errors when creating a new `TCPDF_PARSER` object. See [line 93](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/v0.14.0/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php#L93):

```
@$parser = new \TCPDF_PARSER(ltrim($content));
```

Any fatal error here would also cause the code to exit without a clear error message.

If you're still experiencing the issue with v0.14, edit `Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php` and remove the `@`. You should be able to see what goes wrong.